# Re-expanding a compressed dataframe to include zero values in missing rows

Tags: r

Given a dataset in the following form:

```
> Test
   Pos     Watson Crick Total
1  39023      0     0     0
2  39024      0     0     0
3  39025      0     0     0
4  39026      2     1     3
5  39027      0     0     0
6  39028      0     4     4
7  39029      0     0     0
8  39030      0     1     1
9  39031      0     0     0
10 39032      0     0     0
11 39033      0     0     0
12 39034      1     0     1
13 39035      0     0     0
14 39036      0     0     0
15 39037      3     0     3
16 39038      2     0     2
17 39039      0     0     0
18 39040      0     1     1
19 39041      0     0     0
20 39042      0     0     0
21 39043      0     0     0
22 39044      0     0     0
23 39045      0     0     0
```

I can compress these data to remove zero rows with the following code:

```
a=subset(Test, Total!=0)

> a
    Pos     Watson Crick Total
 4  39026      2     1     3
 6  39028      0     4     4
 8  39030      0     1     1
 12 39034      1     0     1
 15 39037      3     0     3
 16 39038      2     0     2
 18 39040      0     1     1
```

How would I code the reverse transformation? i.e. To convert dataframe `a` back into the original form of `Test`.

More specifically: without any access to the original data, how would I re-expand the data (to include all sequential "Pos" rows) for an arbitrary range of Pos?

Here, the `ID` column is irrelevant. In a real example, the `ID` numbers are just row numbers created by R. In a real example, the compressed dataset will have sequential `ID` numbers.

Comment: In this case or in general?

Comment: Both? I'm here to learn.

Comment: Your ID numbers are unique?

Comment: I don't think an answer to this question would be helpful for your real case, if your data.frame is already "compressed" and if you don't know the original one.

Comment: @Pascal. The only thing missing in the compressed form are sequential "Pos" rows. These simply need refilling with zeros in Watson, Crick, and Total to rebuild the original structure.

Comment: OK, if your `Pos` is supposed to be with no gap.

Comment: @ docendo: I ran your code and it returned: 
> merge(expand.grid(Pos = levels(a$Pos)), a, all.x = TRUE)
[1] Pos    Watson Crick  Total 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
I don't know what you mean by using lapply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another possibility, using base `R`. Unless you explicitly provide the initial and the final value of `Pos`, the first and the last index value in the restored dataframe will correspond to the values given in the "compressed" dataframe `a`:

```
restored <- data.frame(Pos=(a$Pos[1]:a$Pos[nrow(a)])) # change range if required
restored <- merge(restored,a, all=TRUE)
restored[is.na(restored)] <- 0
#> restored
#     Pos Watson Crick Total
#1  39026      2     1     3
#2  39027      0     0     0
#3  39028      0     4     4
#4  39029      0     0     0
#5  39030      0     1     1
#6  39031      0     0     0
#7  39032      0     0     0
#8  39033      0     0     0
#9  39034      1     0     1
#10 39035      0     0     0
#11 39036      0     0     0
#12 39037      3     0     3
#13 39038      2     0     2
#14 39039      0     0     0
#15 39040      0     1     1
```

Possibly the last step can be combined with the `merge` function by using the `na.action` option correctly, but I didn't find out how.

Comment: xlim=39020
range=30
restored <- data.frame(Pos=(xlim:(xlim+range))) # change range if required
restored <- merge(restored,a, all=TRUE)
restored[is.na(restored)] <- 0

Comment: @Matt Glad that I could help. I like your solution to extend the range.

Comment: My thanks comment seems to have been deleted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to know at least the `Pos` values you want to fill in. Then, it's a combination of `join` and `mutate` operations in `dplyr`.

```
Test <- read.table(text = "
   Pos     Watson Crick Total
1  39023      0     0     0
2  39024      0     0     0
3  39025      0     0     0
4  39026      2     1     3
5  39027      0     0     0
6  39028      0     4     4
7  39029      0     0     0
8  39030      0     1     1
9  39031      0     0     0
10 39032      0     0     0
11 39033      0     0     0
12 39034      1     0     1
13 39035      0     0     0
14 39036      0     0     0
15 39037      3     0     3
16 39038      2     0     2
17 39039      0     0     0
18 39040      0     1     1
19 39041      0     0     0
20 39042      0     0     0
21 39043      0     0     0
22 39044      0     0     0")

library(dplyr)

Nonzero <- Test %>% filter(Total > 0)

All_Pos <- Test %>% select(Pos)

Reconstruct <-
  All_Pos %>%
  left_join(Nonzero) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)), Watson, Crick, Total)
```

In my code, `All_Pos` contains all valid positions as a one-column data frame; the `mutate_each()` call converts NA values to zeros. If you only know the largest `MaxPos`, you can construct it using

```
All_Pos <- data.frame(seq_len(MaxPos))
```

Comment: Thanks. but I think I have confused the issue by trying to provide a snapshot of the data. The real data will begin at Pos value 0 and extend well beyond the example. The compressed data will be a compression of this entire dataset. I would then like to re-expand the data between two arbitrary row positions. There should be no need (as far as I can see) to store removed rows in a separate vector.

Comment: No, without the snapshot it would have been much more difficult to help. If you know the maximal value for `Pos`, you can easily construct `All_Pos <- data.frame(Pos = seq_len(MaxPos))` and go from there.

Comment: It might be much faster to work with the compressed data in the first place; it depends on your application if that's possible.

Comment: Clarification: there will be no access to the original data once compressed. Are you suggesting I can obtain the All_Pos purely from the compressed form? My application is to apply a smoothing function to the data. As far as I am able to code, this requires me to re-expand the zero-containining rows for the region of interest to be smoothed.

Comment: All you need `MaxPos`. What smoothing function are you using? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I am using a Hann smoothing function (or user-specifed window size). I am pretty sure it requires the zeros to be present in my implementation. But as you suggest...perhaps there are alternatives...